# Require csv in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have the following in my controller:

```
  private
  def csv_to_array(file)
    csv = CSV::parse(File.open(file, 'r') {|f| f.read })
    fields = csv.shift
    csv.collect { |record| Hash[*fields.zip(record).flatten ] }
  end
```

And it throws this issue:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant FController::CSV):
  app/controllers/f_controller.rb:27:in `csv_to_array'
  app/controllers/f_controller.rb:9:in `import'
```

It's my understanding that `csv` is included by default in the ruby toolkit, thus not needing to be required. What's causing this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is in the standard library, but you still have to require it:

```
require 'csv'
```

This is one of the differences betweeen core and std-lib.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the core vs std-lib. However, adding require 'csv' to the top of my controller still gives me the same error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Make sure you restarted the server and that you put it in the correct controller at the very top. Also check for typos. I don't see how this could fail.